# Uglify and mangle $scope variables and functions

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, uglifyjs, uglifyjs2

Is there any way to achieve that without breaking the code?
I have tried mangleProperties but indeed my code is not working, even after using regex and 'controller as' feature (https://daveceddia.com/convert-scope-to-controlleras/).

```
gulp.task('useref', ['ng_annotate2'], function (done) {
  gulp.src('./www/index.html')
    .pipe(useref())
    .pipe(gulpif('*.js', uglify({
      mangleProperties: {
        regex: /something$scope/
      }
    })))
    .pipe(gulpif('*.css', minifyCss()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/dist'))
    .on('end', done);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you define your controller in Implicit Annotation like this

```
someModule.controller('MyController', function($scope, greeter) {
  // ...
});
```

then you can not minify your code.

So use Inline Array Annotation to define your controller like this

```
someModule.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'greeter', function($scope, greeter) {
  // ...
}]);
```

for more information read this [Dependency Injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)

Comment: Thanks Durgpal but this is not really what I was looking for as my ng_annotate gulp task is already doing what you mentioned. What I'm looking for is how to minify $scope.function1() in D.t() for instance.. For now I can only achieve D.function1().